# Passar como parametro para o Jasper um Objeto

Tags: jsf, ireport, jasper

Estou tentando criar um relatório, agora ele já está gerando, mas apenas quando eu passo no JasperPrint o JREmptyDataSource().

```
JasperPrint impressoraJasper = JasperFillManager.fillReport("D:/Edital.jasper", parametros, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Ele cria o edital mas com todos os campos nulos. Então eu tentei criar um Array com meu Bean, mas não obtive sucesso, pois dentro do iReport usei 3 classes com inner joins. E eu não consigo passar 3 beans diferentes.

No meu ManagedBean eu tenho um objeto Edital já preenchido, e o meu relatório só recebe um único parâmetro, que é o ID desse edital. Preciso mesmo de um dataSource? É com ele que to tendo problema. Como faço para passar apenas esse ID pro Jasper e ele gerar meu edital?

Meu código:

```
public void imprimirRelatorio() throws IOException, ParseException {

    HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
    parametros.put("ID_EDITAL", edital.getIdEdital());
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    try {

        Edital[] beanArray = new Edital[1];
        beanArray[0] = edital;  

        JRBeanArrayDataSource dsColecao1 = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(beanArray, false);

       JasperPrint impressoraJasper = JasperFillManager.fillReport("D:/Edital2.jasper", parametros, dsColecao1);

        File pdf = new File("relatorio2.pdf");
        pdf.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream arquivo = new FileOutputStream(pdf);
        System.out.println(pdf.getAbsolutePath());

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(impressoraJasper, arquivo);

        arquivo.flush();
        arquivo.close();  

    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }          
}
```

**EDIT:** Fiz um relatório que usa apenas um bean (sem inner joins), coloquei esse bean em um array com uma única posição e funcionou. Agora como colocar o resto dos beans?